# Obtener propiedades de un objeto el cual pertenece a otro objeto

Tags: javascript, poo

Saludos.

Llevo intentando saber como poder sacar las **propiedades** de un objeto que esta a la vez dentro de otro objeto.
Esto viene a raíz de un libro de programación.

El código es el siguiente.

1º tenemos el objeto :

```
    function Concesionario(cod_oficina_in,ciudad_in,responsabilidad_in){
    this.cod_oficina = cod_oficina_in;
    this.ciudad = ciudad_in;
    this.responsabilidad = responsabilidad_in;
    }


   function Coche(marca_in,modelo_in,anyo_in,concesionario_in){
   this.marca = marca_in;
   this.modelo = modelo_in;
   this.anyo = anyo_in;
   this.concesionario = concesionario_in;
   }

  var concesionario_atocha = new Concesionario('281','Madrid','Pedro Bravo');

  var mi_coche = new Coche('Citroen','C4','2010',concesionario_atocha);
```

Por medio de un **for..in** puedo sacar las propiedades de un objeto en este caso **mi_coche**

Mi pregunta es :

¿ Còmo puedo mostrar o almacenar las propiedades del objeto **concesionario_atocha** al que pertenece como propiedad del objeto **mi_coche** mediante 
un bucle for..in , for , while o mediante una función.. ?

```
 for( indice in mi_coche){
      document.write(....propiedades.concesionario_atocha ... ? )
      }
```

Gracias por vuestra atención.
Ya es una duda que quiero sacarme de la cabeza ya que he probado de todo , bucle for..in anidados , for anidados , while , uso de arrays.. ni idea.

Comment: por favor revisa la solucion que dan [aca] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690706/recursively-looping-through-an-object-to-build-a-property-list)

lo que realizan ahi es una recursividad.

Answer (score 2):

Tus objetos son en realidad instancias de clase con propiedades públicas, por lo que al iterar sobre ellos vas a recoger también métodos del prototipo que no vendrían en un objeto plano.

Como sea, puedes iterar sobre el concecionario haciendo:

```
for(var key in mi_coche.concesionario) {
    console.log(mi_coche.concesionario[key]);
}
```

Como dije antes, probablemente al hacer eso te van a salir más llaves que las declaradas en el constructor de Concesionario. Para dejarlas fuera, tendrías que hacer:

```
for(var key in mi_coche.concesionario) {
    if(mi_coche.concesionario.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
       console.log(mi_coche.concesionario[key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Esta es una solución a lo que buscas @Sin Nombre..hasOwnProperty() te permite saber cuales son propiedades del objeto hijo, y descartar los de la clase base...sí se complicaría si utilizaras una cadena de herencia más extensa, pero para 2 niveles sería suficiente siendo aquello lo que intentas.

Comment: Perfecta solución , solamente quería saber como se hacía por sí alguna vez tengo que hacerlo. Genial , muchas gracias

Comment: Si consideras que esta respuesta ayudó a solucionar tu duda/problema, considera marcarla como correcta.

Answer (score 1):

Estas confundiendo las cosas, la palabra reservada new se utiliza para crear un nuevo objeto referenciando al contructor de una clase, por lo tanto no se utiliza para funciones(acciones de objetos)

En tu codigo estas utilizando la palabra reservada new para una funcion.

```
var concesionario_atocha = new Concesionario('281','Madrid','Pedro Bravo');
```

las funciones vienen a ser las acciones de los objetos, una buena practica es nombrar con verbos a las funciones, como manejar, correr, andar, nadar, etc.

tu codigo:

```
function Concesionario(cod_oficina_in,ciudad_in,responsabilidad_in)
    this.cod_oficina = cod_oficina_in;
    this.ciudad = ciudad_in;
    this.responsabilidad = responsabilidad_in;
    }
```

el codigo de arriba es una funcion, no se puede instanciar objetos de una funcion, debemos volverlo Clase, de la siguiente manera:

```
 Class Concesionario{
   int cod_oficina ;
   String ciudad;  
   String responsabidad;



public Concesionario(cod_oficina_in,ciudad_in,responsabilidad_in){
     this.cod_oficina = cod_oficina_in;
     this.ciudad = ciudad_in;
     this.responsabilidad = responsabilidad_in;
    }
  }
```

ahora respondiendo a tu pregunta:
puedes acceder creando funciones get

```
por ejemplo:

public int getCodOficina(){
return cod_oficina;
}
```

Comment: @SinNombre mi pregunta para ti es: quieres iterar sobre un objeto en un for?

Comment: si , quiero iterar sobre el objeto mi_coche y poder sacar también dentro de esta iteración las propiedades del objeto concesionario_atocha que es a la vez propiedad del objeto mi_coche.

Comment: edite mi respuesta

Comment: No necesita declarar clases. Una función es un constructor válido. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

Comment: @amenadiel gracias por la correccion, serian usadas como estructuras de c++?

Comment: Ni idea. Cuando aprendí POO ya hacía mucho tiempo que no tocaba una línea de c++

Comment: hermano x-rw, en javascript varía respecto a los lenguajes de clases, en realidad el enfoque sugerido es válido en JS, y se llama seudoclásico, o también se le llama prototipado debido a la forma específica en que JS le agrega una propiedad Prototype, a los objetos, que es el mecanismo por el cual es posible lograr la POO más o menos similar a la Clásica de Java o C++, o  POO al estilo JS.

Comment: Perdona que te corrija pero una forma de crear objetos mediante constructores en JavaScript es usando funciones constructoras , la cual es la que he usado siguiendo la guía oficial de Mozilla https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabajando_con_objectos la version ECMAScript 6 tiene la posibilidad crear clases mediante la palabra reservada class e instanciar objetos mediante la palabra reservada 'constructor' pero esta en fase experimental